# How do I get normal users to send a JWT in their header with node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, http-headers

I don't know why no online tutorials are covering this but "normal" users don't make GET/POST requests using Postman... they make these requests just using their browser.

So, after sending a user's new JWT to them, how do you ensure that the users sends new requests with JWT in the header? My code uses the "authorization": "Bearer [access_token]" keywords in the request header, and the typical website user won't directly edit these fields in their browser.

To send the JWT in the header on every single page of the website once the user is logged in, how are you supposed to do that?

Online I see how some people say "store the JWT in cookies" but that feels like it defeats the point of JWTs. They're information stored on the client side not on one server's side.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to never store tokens in the browser and instead use the BFF-pattern.

These two videos will describe the BFF concepts and why it is a necessity:

- [alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&t=2618s)
- [Using the BFF pattern to secure SPA and Blazor Applications](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBFx3MSu1Rc)